# If $L$ is a continuous linear form on a dense subspace of a Hilbert space $H$, what do we mean by the claim $L\in H$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

Let

- $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $D(\mathfrak a)$ be a dense subspace of $H$
- $\mathfrak a:D(\mathfrak a)\times D(\mathfrak a)\to\mathbb R$ be bounded, i.e. $\exists c\ge 0$ with $$\left|\mathfrak a(u,v)\right|\le c\left\|u\right\|_{\mathfrak a}\left\|v\right\|_{\mathfrak a}\;\;\;\text{for all }u,v\in D(\mathfrak a)$$ where $$\left\|u\right\|_{\mathfrak a}:=\sqrt{\mathfrak a(u,u)+\left\|u\right\|_H^2}\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in D(\mathfrak a)$$

Now, let $$D(A):=\left\{u\in D(\mathfrak a)\mid\exists v\in H:\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)=\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,v\rangle_H\right|_{D(\mathfrak a)}\right\}\;.\tag 1$$ It's easy to see that $$u\in D(A)\Leftrightarrow u\in D(\mathfrak a)\text{ and }\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)\text{ is }H\text{-continuous}\;.\tag 2$$

> I've seen that many people write $$D(A)=\left\{u\in D(\mathfrak a):\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)\in H\right\}\;.\tag 3$$ So, my question is: Why are $(1)$ and $(2)$ equivalent?

I guess $(2)$ has to be interpreted in a suitable sense. Clearly, if $u\in D(A)$, we know that $u\in D(\mathfrak a)$ such that $\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)$ is $H$-continuous. Since $D(\mathfrak a)$ is dense in $H$, there is a unique $F\in H'$ with $$\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)=\left.F\right|_{D(\mathfrak a)}$$ by the [bounded linear transformation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension#Theorem). Thus, there is a unique extension of $\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)$ to $H$. Since $H'\cong H$ we could justify the notation $\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)\in H$.

For the other direction, $\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)\in H$ would imply the existence of a unique extension $F\in H'$ of $\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)$ to $H$. Since $H'\cong H$, there is a unique $v\in H$ with $$F=\langle\;\cdot\;,v\rangle_H$$ and hence $$\mathfrak a(\;\cdot\;,u)=\left.\langle\;\cdot\;,v\rangle_H\right|_{D(\mathfrak a)}\;.$$

> Is this the way we need to understand $(3)$?

Comment: can you simplify your questions ? you don't need all those details.

Comment: and in general, if $T : D(X) \to Y$ is bounded with $D(X)$ a dense subspace of $X$, then it can be extended to a bounded operator $X \to Y$ by considering for each $x \in X$ a sequence $x_n \in D(X)$ such that $x_n \to x$

Comment: By the way: since $\mathfrak{a}$ is bilinear, your definition of "boundedness" is trivially satisfied by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if $\mathfrak{a}$ is non-negative, i.e., $\mathfrak{a}(u,u) \ge 0$ for all $u \in D(\mathfrak{a})$.

Comment: @gerw It's the definition of continuity which you can find in [Definition 1.4 (3)](https://books.google.de/books?id=eSZqJOaiRUwC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22In+this+section,+we+consider+sesquilinear+forms+which+do+not+act+on+the+whole%22&source=bl&ots=BVfxi3ZlfQ&sig=JdVyV28TKWxWPmMMA4XH0FcmWU4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiln4HE-ObNAhWLPBQKHRUuCAkQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=%22In%20this%20section%2C%20we%20consider%20sesquilinear%20forms%20which%20do%20not%20act%20on%20the%20whole%22&f=false) in *Analysis of Heat Equations on Domains* by *El Maati Ouhabaz*.

Comment: @user1952009 Which "details" are you talking about? The main part of my question is my interpretation of $(3)$. And if I want to ask how I need to interpret $(3)$, I should introduce the necessary objects.

Comment: @user1952009 And related to what you've said about $T$: This is exactly the argument which is used in the proof of the [bounded linear transformation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension#Theorem) which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: all the useless details. really, once you understood it, your question can be written in 3 lines (see how short are the answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you would ask me, it is meant in the sense you mentioned. Since a Hilbert space is isometric isomorphic to its dual space due to the Riesz representation theorem you can identify the functionals in $H'$ with their riesz representers in $H$. I did that frequently in my bachelor thesis. It is not the most formal way but you can give shorter definitions and assumptions by using this identification.